# How to use thumbnail slick carousel in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slick.js

I am using **[Slick for Vue.js](https://github.com/staskjs/vue-slick)** for thumbnail carousel as like this https://codepen.io/pjmtokyo/full/JYyjew and everything works fine but not only click-based changing like when I click on thumbnails not change the main carousel.

Here is my examples code

template:

```
<slick
    ref="slick"
    :options="slickOptions"
    :asNavFor = "$refs.slick2"
>
  <a href="http://placehold.it/2000x1000"><img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000" alt=""></a>
  <a href="http://placehold.it/2000x1000"><img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000" alt=""></a>
  <a href="http://placehold.it/2000x1000"><img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000" alt=""></a>
  <a href="http://placehold.it/2000x1000"><img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000" alt=""></a>
  <a href="http://placehold.it/2000x1000"><img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000" alt=""></a>
</slick>

<slick
    ref="slick2"
    :options="slickOptions2"
    :asNavFor = "$refs.slick"
>
  <a href="http://placehold.it/2000x1000"><img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000" alt=""></a>
  <a href="http://placehold.it/2000x1000"><img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000" alt=""></a>
  <a href="http://placehold.it/2000x1000"><img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000" alt=""></a>
  <a href="http://placehold.it/2000x1000"><img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000" alt=""></a>
  <a href="http://placehold.it/2000x1000"><img src="http://placehold.it/2000x1000" alt=""></a>

                <button class="prev-arrow slick-arrow">
                    <feather type="arrow-left"></feather>
                </button>

                <button class="next-arrow slick-arrow">
                    <feather type="arrow-right"></feather>
                </button>
</slick>
```

Script:

```
export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: { Slick },
    data() {
        return {
            slickOptions: {
                speed: 300,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                cssEase: 'linear',
                fade: true,
                autoplay: true,
                draggable: true,
                prevArrow: '.client-feedback .prev-arrow',
                nextArrow: '.client-feedback .next-arrow'
            },
            slickOptions2: {
                speed: 300,
                slidesToShow: 5,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                cssEase: 'linear',
                autoplay: true,
                centerMode: true,
                draggable: false,
                focusOnSelect: true,
                prevArrow: '.client-thumbnails .prev-arrow',
                nextArrow: '.client-thumbnails .next-arrow',
            },
        };
    },

    methods: {
        next() {
            this.$refs.slick.next();
        },

        prev() {
            this.$refs.slick.prev();
        }
    }
}
```

How to do that as I need

Thanks